# How can I access server file or env variables from VsCode WEB extension for WEB VsCode hosted on my server?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Good afternoon, our team faced with an issue during VsCode web extension development.

We plan to provide a Web version of VsCode hosted on our server to clients.

The user works in the same server (and file system) that hosts the VsCode.

We are trying to create an extension that would read temp credentials from file or env variables or anything else that can be filled by a backend app.

We know that VsCode web extensions are running in the isolated browser sandbox, but still some extensions have the access to backend files.

As an example "AWS Toolkit" extension reads AWS credentials from "~/.aws/credentials" backend file with no issues.

We tried a couple of ways to access backend resources from the web extension (shown below), but none of them works.

Can you please advise how can we reach our goal ?

Result of the code execution:

**tryEnvVars** - return zero as env variables count, when "env" command from VsCode CLI returns a lot of env variables.

**tryFileExists** - returns "FILE NOT FOUND"

**tryOpenTextDocument** -  doesn't open the document in the editor (it won't solve our problem, but still even this feature doesn't work)

**tryFileCreate** -  doesn't create a file

**tryReadDirectory** -  doesn't find anything

The code:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

function sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

function tryEnvVars(){
    let envVarsCount = Object.keys(process.env).length;
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage("ENV VARS COUNT: " + envVarsCount.toString());
}

async function tryFileExists(uri: vscode.Uri)
{
    vscode.workspace.fs.stat(uri).then(
        () => vscode.window.showInformationMessage("FILE FOUND, " + uri.toString()),
        err => vscode.window.showInformationMessage("FILE NOT FOUND, " + err.toString())
    );
}

function tryOpenTextDocument(uri: vscode.Uri){
    vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(uri);
}

function tryFileCreate(uri: vscode.Uri){
        let wsedit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
        wsedit.createFile(uri, {ignoreIfExists: true});
        vscode.workspace.applyEdit(wsedit);
}

function tryReadDirectory(uri: vscode.Uri){
        vscode.workspace.fs.readDirectory(uri).then(doc => {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage("FOUND SOMETHIG IN " + uri.toString());
        });
}

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('testExtension.helloWorld', async () => {
        
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("STARTED");

        tryEnvVars();
        await sleep(10000);

        tryFileExists(vscode.Uri.file("/home/coder/TEST_FILE.txt"))
        tryFileExists(vscode.Uri.file("home/coder/TEST_FILE.txt"))
        await sleep(10000);

        tryFileExists(vscode.Uri.parse('file:~/TEST_FILE.txt'))
        tryFileExists(vscode.Uri.parse("file:./TEST_FILE_LOCAL.txt"))
        await sleep(10000);

        tryOpenTextDocument(vscode.Uri.file("/home/coder/TEST_FILE.txt"));
        tryOpenTextDocument(vscode.Uri.file("home/coder/TEST_FILE.txt"));
        await sleep(10000);

        tryFileCreate(vscode.Uri.file("/home/coder/CREATED_FILE_1.txt"));
        tryFileCreate(vscode.Uri.file("home/coder/CREATED_FILE_2.txt"));
        await sleep(10000);

        tryReadDirectory(vscode.Uri.file("/home/coder/"));
        tryReadDirectory(vscode.Uri.file("home/coder/"));
        tryReadDirectory(vscode.Uri.file("home/coder"));
        await sleep(10000);

        tryReadDirectory(vscode.Uri.file("/home/coder/proj/"));
        tryReadDirectory(vscode.Uri.file("home/coder/proj/"));
        tryReadDirectory(vscode.Uri.file("home/coder/proj"));
        await sleep(10000);

        tryReadDirectory(vscode.Uri.file("."));
        tryReadDirectory(vscode.Uri.file("./"));
        tryReadDirectory(vscode.Uri.file("~/"));
        await sleep(10000);

        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("DONE");
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```